# MapServer WFS service works in QGIS but not in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, wfs, mapserver, data-interoperability

I published a WFS service using MapServer. The source of the WFS layer is a FGDB.

When I add the service in QGIS, it works flawlessly.  When I add the service in ArcMap, all I can see is a layer named NoGeometry.

In ArcMap, I used 'Add Interoperability Connection', I chose the format WFS (Web Feature Service). In the Dataset, I put the the URL `http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\aca\test.map`

See the screenshot for the rest of the parameters.

[image: Parameters]

When I drag the layer to add it to the map, I get this error: "This dataset appears to be invalid. Please verify that your settings or file contents are correct, and try again".

Where is the problem??

Comment: what happens if you use WFS version 1.0.0

Comment: I tried that, no luck...